# adb logcat shows the code for emoji, but reading logcat programmatically loses the information

Tags: java, android

adb logcat captures the following:

I/System.out(10263): TEXT :<\d83d><\de48><\d83d><\de4a><\d83d><\de49><\d83d><\dc35>^M

which is encoding for emoji that shows up in the textview. (ignore the \es in the text above. I couldn't find a way to have the text show up in this post otherwise)

When I read the logcat programmatically using:

```
try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8));




        String line = "";
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("/sdcard/log.txt", "UTF-8");

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                  writer.println(line);
        }
        writer.close();            
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

The same output line is:
I/System.out(10263): TEXT :��������

Any insight? Am I missing a simple encoding parameter between reading from the logs and writing to a file?